# How to add content after my post title on Wordpress ? Only on the post title

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to add some content after post title. So I made a plugin with this code :

```
add_filter('the_title', function ($title) {
        if(is_single()) {
            return $title . " my extra content";
        }
    });
```

Except this code edit all title on the post page (in recent articles section for instance). However I would like to add my content ONLY after the post title. How I can do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to add it to a specific post type?

Comment: I want to add it on the post which is shown

Comment: Which post, though? The first one or what? Your question isn't very clear. Are you displaying a list of posts and only want to change the title of the first one?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'the_title', function ( $title ) {
        if ( is_single() && is_main_query() ) {
            return $title . " my extra content" ;
        }
        return $title ;
    });
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_main_query/

Comment: It's doesn't work. It do the same, my extra content is added several times on the page.

Comment: The problem may come down to your theme or template or page-builder if you're using one. Can you name the theme? Add a link to the page? A screenshot might be helpful, though not as helpful. I also added a line to the example, btw, since you need to return the $title as is if you don't want to remove it.